# Compiling a Plain-TeX file that loads harvmac on TexWorks on windows

Tags: plain-tex, texworks

I had asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103323/how-to-compile-a-tex-file-that-requires-the-file-harvmac-tex) and it was suggested that I use plain TeX.

On TeXworks among the compiling options there is no such thing.

When I try running the file through pdfTeX I get the message,

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) entering extended mode
(C:\Users(some path)\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\plain\harvmac\harvmac.tex
big or little (b/l)?
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I assume you're in the `Terminal` app (command line interface) and have typed `pdftex 9711200v3`. (At least, that's the filename you mentioned in your earlier posting.) When the compilation pauses to prompt your for "b" or "l", type "b", and `pdftex` will complete the compilation without further ado. (If you choose "l", various cryptic warning messages about "Non-PDF special ignored!" will be issued...)

Answer (score 4):

TeXworks is running plain TeX according to your message. The `harvmac` macros are set up expecting 'interactive' input: you have to give it a choice here. At the bottom of the TeXworks window when running TeX is a command entry line, where you should be able to answer the question and press Enter to continue (either option `b` or `l` should work).